# My responsive menu does not display correctly on hover and the menu contents are transparent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, menu

I have a problem with my responsive menu when I switch to a very small window I have my menu displayed but have seen the contents of the page suddenly impossible to click on the links.
So I can't find where I made a mistake.

Thank you...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    let menu = $('#menu');
    let navegation = $('#navegation');
    let scrollZero = 0;

  $('#icon-menu').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
    $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll-y');
    navegation.toggleClass('menu-active');
  });

  $('.submenu').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.submenu').children('.children').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.submenu').children('a').children('.caret').removeClass('rotate');
        $(this).children('a').children('.caret').toggleClass('rotate');
        $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
    });

  $(window).on('click', function(e) {
    if (menu.has(e.target).length == 0 && !menu.is(e.target)) {
      $('.submenu').children('.children').slideUp();
      $('.submenu').children('a').children('.caret').removeClass('rotate');
      if ($(this).width() < 900 && navegation.hasClass('menu-active')) {
        $('#icon-menu').trigger('click');
      }
    }
  });

  $(window).on('load scroll resize', function () {
    let positionScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (positionScrollY < scrollZero) {
        menu.removeClass('scroll-down');
      } else {
          $('.submenu').children('.children').slideUp();
          $('.submenu').children('a').children('.caret').removeClass('rotate');
          menu.addClass('scroll-down');
        }
      scrollZero = positionScrollY;
      if (positionScrollY == 0) {
        menu.removeClass('scroll-down');
      }
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll-y');

    if ($(this).width() > 900 && !navegation.hasClass('menu-active')) {
      $('#icon-menu').addClass('fa-bars').removeClass('fa-times');
      navegation.removeClass('menu-active');
    } else if ($(this).width() < 900 && navegation.hasClass('menu-active')) {
        $('body').addClass('no-scroll-y');
      }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
    background-color: #fefefe;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
-------- Navigation
\*------------------------------------*/

.no-scroll-y {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("images/noise.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
}

.scroll-down,
.scroll-down .btn-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.menu-bar {
  display: none;
}

header nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset,
               0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}

header nav {
  max-width: 1270px;
  height: 54px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
          transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
}

header nav ul {
  /*display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;*/
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #1D3B6A;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 10px;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #FC5342;
}

header nav ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

header nav ul li a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #1D3B6A;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

header nav ul li a span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header nav ul li .caret {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease all;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

header nav ul li .caret.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}

header nav ul li .children {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 280px;
  right: 0;
  top: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,21,64,.1),0 10px 20px rgba(0,21,64,.05);
  display: none;
  -webkit-animation: children .4s cubic-bezier(.7,.006,.2,1);
  animation: children .4s cubic-bezier(.7,.006,.2,1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  z-index: 10000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes children {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1rem) scale(.9);
    transform: translateY(-1rem) scale(.9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes children {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1rem) scale(.9);
    transform: translateY(-1rem) scale(.9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*
header nav ul li:hover .children,
header nav ul li:focus .children,
header nav ul li:active .children {
  display: block;
}
*/

header nav ul li .children li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header nav .right {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li .children li a {
  display: block;
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

header nav ul li .children li a:hover {
  color: #AAB74E;
  font-size: 15px;
}

header nav ul li .children li a span {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
-------- Content
\*------------------------------------*/
.hita-main {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1270px;
}

#hita-top {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.hita-row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.hita-m-1,
.hita-m-2,
.hita-m-3 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
-------- Responsive ( Min )
\*------------------------------------*/
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .hita-main {
    max-width: 460px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .hita-main {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .hita-main {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .hita-main {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .hita-main {
    max-width: 1270px;
  }
  .hita-m-1, .hita-m-2, .hita-m-3 {
    float: left;
  }
  .hita-m-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hita-m-2 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .hita-m-1 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

/*------------------------------------*\
-------- Responsive ( Max )
\*------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .menu-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-bar .btn-menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("images/noise.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: #193767;
    cursor: auto;
    display: block;
    font: bold 25px 'Arial', sans-serif;
    left: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease all;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .menu-bar .btn-menu span {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  header nav {
    height: calc(100% - 69px);
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(70px - 1px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
            transform-origin: left;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(90deg);
            transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(90deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease all;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #012345;
    background-image: url("images/noise.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
  header nav ul {
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
  }
  header nav ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
  }
  header nav ul li .caret {
    float: right;
  }
  header nav ul li .children {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("images/noise.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
  header nav ul li:hover .children,
  header nav ul li:focus .children,
  header nav ul li:active .children {
    display: none;
  }
  header nav ul li .children li a {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  header nav .right {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Menu dropdown</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/css/v4-shims.css">

</head>
<body>

  <header id="menu">
    <div class="menu-bar">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-menu">
      <span id="icon-menu" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav id="navegation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Lorem</a>
          <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Lorem</a>
          <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Lorem</a>
          <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem #5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <!-- +++++ Section - Content +++++ -->
  <div class="hita-main" id="hita-top">
    <div class="hita-row">
      <div class="hita-m-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      
      <!-- Menu Right -->
      <div class="hita-m-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is if someone could help me explain or I made a mistake thank you ...

Comment: Please edit the title to be in English

Comment: Your title should be something like "My responsive menu does not display when hovering"

Comment: Could be a z-index issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add z-index to the nav link in order to bring it to cover the div.

```
header nav ul li a {
    color: #1D3B6A;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 10px;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    z-index: 1;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help I found my error I forgot the z-index but not where you told me but I found thank you...

```css
  header nav {
 height: calc(100% - 69px);
 left: 0;
 margin: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: auto;
 position: fixed;
 top: calc(70px - 1px);
 -webkit-transform-origin: left;
         transform-origin: left;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(90deg);
         transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(90deg);
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease all;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
 width: 80%;
    background-color: #012345;
    background-image: url("images/noise.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
 
  z-index: 1;
  }
```